# Finding cells used in SUMIFS formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very large and complicated Excel document that includes a large and complicated SUMIFS formula. Is there an easy way to tell which cells are used in that formula?

Comment: I suspect the best you're going to be able to do is rewrite your `=SUMIFS()` formula as an `=IF()` formula that you copy to a column on every row.

Answer (score 0):

Under Formula Tab in the Excel ribbon. Check out Formula Auditing section.

Click on the cell with formula. Then click "Trace Precedents" - This will give you an arrow guide. Showing the formula may help at the same time.